# Scaffolding migration up/down shows Empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I want to create a new datatable in my database.
I ran Add-Migration items, it shows empty for both up() and down()

```
namespace myapp.Migrations
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class items : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
}
```

I have a model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public int defineindex { get; set; }
}

public class ItemContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I also created a mapping when the above code doesnt generate useful scaffold. But it still didnt solve my problem.

Comment: Did you build before you ran add-migrations?
and have you configured an Id field for he item class? ef likes it if you have an id field in the class

Comment: I built before ran add-migrations. I tried to add "public int Id { get; set; }"
but still getting the same empty up/down.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ContextKey value in my Migrations/Configuration.cs for my EF, which is set to a class name. So my EF will only care about that class. I need to put my DbSets all under that class for it to work instead of creating a new class.